# How can I make a proper walk cycle following a path for a four-legged animal (tiger in this case)?

Tags: animation, rigging

How do I make a proper walk cycle for a tiger, following an irregular path?
For bipeds there are several tools, and AI even, to make a cycle that you set to follow a path. Fine. But with a four-legged animal, there are problems when following a curved path, since the whole body just "drifts" around. Manually curving the spine to get it right is really hard and time consuming. There just HAS to be a better way of calculating this?
Also, the walk cycle by itself, where do I find great cycles for tigers? That don't slide in the steps etc. I just want my tiger to walk in a trustworthy fashion.

Comment: Hello, there are methods to create non-slipping walk cycles, there's no reason why it should not work for 4 legs

Comment: Good to hear. Do you possibly know what those methods are, or point me in the right direction?